# Añadir lista de imágenes pdf en latex mediante python

Tags: python, latex

Mi objetivo es representar una lista de gráficas en pdf en latex. Y tengo que hacerlo mediante python.

He conseguido hacer esto pero me da error.

¿Alguien me ayuda?

```
f = open('informe.tex', 'w+')

f.write("""\documentclass{article}"""
"""\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}"""
"""\usepackage{graphicx}"""
"""\\title{ANALISIS DINAMICO DE VIADUCTO PARA FERROCARRIL DE ALTA 
VELOCIDAD}"""
"""\date{CURVAS ENVOLVENTES DE ACELERACION}"""
"""\\begin{document}""")

for i in range(1,46):
    f.write(
    """\\begin{figure}"""
    """\centering"""
    """\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva"""+str(i)+"""}"""

"""\graphicspath{{Directorio donde tengo las gráficas}}"""
"""\end{figure}""")

f.write("""\end{document}""")
```

Las triples comillas es para introducir párrafos diferentes

Un saludo

Este es el mensaje de error:

> (no line number): Runaway argument? {{C:\Users ^^Glfbe\Desktop \M
>   áster\Estructuras \SEM \Tallerpython a\ETC. ! File ended while
>   scanning use of \graphicspath.  
>                   \par  <*> informe.tex

Esto es lo que me aparece en latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\graphicspath{{C:\Userslfbe\Desktop\Máster\Estructuras\SEM\Tallerpython allerpython\envolventes\GRAFICAS\}}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva1}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva2}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva3}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva4}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva5}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva6}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva7}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva8}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva9}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva10}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva11}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva12}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva13}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva14}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva15}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva16}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva17}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva18}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva19}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva20}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva21}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva22}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva23}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva24}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva25}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva26}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva27}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva28}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva29}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva30}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva31}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva32}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva33}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva34}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva35}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva36}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva37}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva38}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva39}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva40}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva41}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva42}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva43}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva44}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva45}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: Sabés la sintaxis de LaTeX? Sugiero que le des un vistazo al archivo generado a ver si hay algo raro. Si podés agregalo a la publicación.

Comment: La sintáxis LaTex parece correcta, revisa el nombre del path, por el error pareciera no estar interpretándolo correctamente: `{C:\Users ^^Glfbe\Desktop \M áster\Estructuras \SEM \Tallerpython a\ETC`, prueba mover la imágenes a un path más sencillo tipo `c:\Temp` y tomar las imágenes desde ahí, empieza probando eso. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

### Indagaciones

El error de latex sucede en la línea que declaras el `\graphicspath` y latex concretamente muestra parte de esa ruta:

> C:\Users ^^Glfbe\Desktop[...]

El carácter `^^G` es sospechoso. Sería interesante ver en tu código cómo creas la línea en cuestión, pero en la parte python que lo hace has ocultado esa ruta, y sólo se ve:

```
"""\graphicspath{{Directorio donde tengo las gráficas}}"""
```

Pero precisamente esa línea es la clave del problema. Así que habrá que hacer de detective :-)

- En la ruta volcada por el error de LaTeX se ve el carácter no imprimible `^^G`, que es la forma en que TeX representa un ASCII 7 (`^^A` representa el ascii 1, `^^B` el ascii 2, etc..)
- El ASCII 7 es el carácter "bell" (pitido), que puede formar parte de una cadena python (o C) si lo escribes como `"\a"` ([véase](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)).
- Por tanto sospecho que la parte que ocultaste en el fuente era algo como:

  ```py
  """\graphicspath{{C:\Users\alfbe\Desktop\...}}"""
  ```

  Lo que tiene sentido viendo que el usuario se llama Alfonso :-)

### ¿Qué ha pasado por tanto?

El carácter `\` es especial dentro de un string. Es una forma de poder introducir caracteres no imprimibles como parte de una cadena. En concreto `\n` es bastante famoso (representa el retorno de carro), pero hay más, como el `\a` que hemos visto que es el ASCII BELL. La lista de estos caracteres especiales está [aqui](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html). Si lo que va tras la barra no es uno de los casos reconocidos, entonces la barra no se interpreta de forma especial. Así, `\U` no es un carácter especial y por tanto no se interpreta.

En definitiva, en la cadena `"\Users\alfbe"`, `\U` representa dos caracteres (`\` y `U`) mientras que `\a` representa solo uno (el ASCII BELL).

Tu código está lleno de `\` como parte de un string, y todos ellos son potencial fuente de problemas ya que, dependiendo de qué letra vaya detrás, pueden ser interpretados como asciis especiales.

Hay dos formas de evitar el problema:

1. Duplicar cada `\` escribiendo en su lugar `\\`. De hecho, en algunos sitios lo has hecho, como en `\\begin`.
2. Poner una `r` delante de la apertura de comillas, así: `r"\Users\alfbe"`. Esta `r` dice a python que trate la cadena "raw", es decir, que no intente interpretar el `\` como un carácter especial. Así no hay que duplicarlos.

Por otro lado, ya que usas la triple comilla para poder escribir varias líneas, no necesitas cerrarla al final de cada línea y volver a abrirla en la siguiente, por lo que tu código podría reorganizarse un poco y quedar así:

```py
preambulo = r"""
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{ANALISIS DINAMICO DE VIADUCTO PARA FERROCARRIL DE ALTA 
VELOCIDAD}
\date{CURVAS ENVOLVENTES DE ACELERACION}
\graphicspath{{Directorio donde tengo las gráficas}}
\begin{document}"""

plantilla_figura = r"""
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{enva%d}
\end{figure}"""

epilogo = r"""\end{document}"""

f = open('informe.tex', 'w+')
f.write(preambulo)
for i in range(1,46):
    f.write(plantilla_figura % i)
f.write(epilogo)
```

**Postdata**
Y quizás, después de todo, la cosa siga fallando debido a que la ruta del `\graphicspath` contenga espacios. Es bien conocida la aversión de LaTeX hacia los nombres de carpeta o fichero con espacios...